# R sum row values based on column name

Tags: r

I have a dataset with over 10,000 columns and 10,000 rows. I am trying to add values of rows based on column names.

The dataset looks something like this

```
data <- tibble(date = c('1/1/2018','2/1/2018','3/1/2018'),
              x1 = c(1, 11, 111),
              x2 = c(2, 22, 222),
              x1_1 = c(3, 333, 333),
              x2_1 = c(4, 44, 44),
              x1_2 = c(5, 55, 555),
              x2_2 = c(6, 66, 666),)
```

I am trying to create a new table which includes the date column, an x1 column and an x2 column where the value of x1 for row 1 = 1+3+5, value of x2 for row 2 = 22+44+66, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned that column names in my actual dataset are not limited to x1 and x2. It goes up to x2000 so naming columns individually would not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a for loop approach. I use `stringr` but we could just as easily use base regex functions to keep it dependency-free.

```
library(stringr)
name_stems = unique(str_replace(names(data)[-1], "_.*", ""))
result = data[, "date", drop = FALSE]
for(i in seq_along(name_stems)) {
  result[[name_stems[i]]] = 
    rowSums(data[
      str_detect(
        names(data),
        pattern = paste0(name_stems[i], "_")
      )
    ])
}

result
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   date        x1    x2
#   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1/1/2018     9    12
# 2 2/1/2018   399   132
# 3 3/1/2018   999   932
```

Comment: While this works fine for the example above, I run into an issue with my actual dataset. It seems that for x1 for example, the rowSums includes not only x1, x1_1 and x1_2 but also any column that starts with x1 (e.g. x10, x10_1, x11, x100, etc.). Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Sure, we can include the `_` in the pattern. Editing now.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I've added a line of code after line 3 to add a "_" to the end of any column (except date) which doesn't contain a "_" as the above code does not include x1 in the sum, just x1_1, x1_2, etc. `data <- rename_with(data, .fn = ~paste0(., "_"), .cols = c(-contains("_"),-contains("date")))`

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the *wide* format. One way of achieving your goal is transforming the data into the *long* format, then grouping them based on indices (x1 and x2), compute the sums for each group for each date, and finally transform the results back to the *wide* formats to create columns based on the indices.

```
library(tidyverse)

data |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x"), values_to = "x.values") |>
    mutate(xgroup = substr(name, 1,2)) |> 
    group_by(date,xgroup) |>
    summarise(xsums = sum(x.values)) |> 
    pivot_wider(values_from = xsums, names_from = xgroup )

#  date        x1    x2
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1/1/2018     9    12
#2 2/1/2018   399   132
#3 3/1/2018   999   932
```

### Updates

In order to include only columns `x1` and `x1_`, and exclude any other column even though it starts with `x1`, the following regular expression pattern can be used : `"x1$|(x1_).*"`. The similar pattern can be used to include only columns `x2` and `x2_`. For example:

```
s <- c("x100_1", "x10", "x1", "x1_1", "x1_2", "x2", "x2_1", "x2_2", "x20", "x20_1")
s
#[1] "x100_1" "x10"    "x1"     "x1_1"   "x1_2"   "x2"     "x2_1"   "x2_2"   "x20"   
#[10] "x20_1" 

s |> str_extract("x1$|(x1_).*")
#[1] NA     NA     "x1"   "x1_1" "x1_2" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA

s |> str_extract("x2$|(x2_).*")
#[1] NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     "x2"   "x2_1" "x2_2" NA     NA
```

This pattern can then be used to create a group that consists of `x1` and `x1_` columns only and another group that consists of `x2` and `x2_` columns only.

Here is the full code:

```
data |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x"), values_to = "x.values") |>
    mutate(xgroup = case_when(str_detect(name, "x1$|(x1_).*")~"x1",
                              str_detect(name, "x2$|(x2_).*")~"x2")) |>
    group_by(date,xgroup) |>
    summarise(xsums = sum(x.values)) |> 
    pivot_wider(values_from = xsums, names_from = xgroup )
```

Comment: This one works well too. However, I have the same issue with this as with Gregor's solution. i.e. While this works fine for the example above, I run into an issue with my actual dataset. It seems that for x1 for example, the sum includes not only x1, x1_1 and x1_2 but also any column that starts with x1 (e.g. x10, x10_1, x11, x100, etc.). Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: OK I see. What about x2 group? Does it also include every column that starts with x2 too?

Comment: That's correct, if I run the code for the following df 'data <- tibble(date = c('a','b','c'),
               x1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
               x2 = c(1, 2, 3),
               x1_1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),
               x2_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
               x100 = c(10, 20, 30),
               x201_1 = c(100, 200, 300))'
               The result table has two columns x1 (which is the sum of x1,x1_1 and x100) and x2 (which is the sum of x2, x2_1 and x201_1)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if the updated code can work accurately as you expected.

Comment: Pivoting was my first instinct as well, but with *such* wide data (10k columns is a lot of columns!) this could be very inefficient memory-wise. It would be my first choice method if the data wasn't so wide.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas: Thank you for your comment. Really interesting, and I agree. Need to figure out how to make pivoting more efficient for such wide data.

Comment: It's a fundamental problem - you have a large data structure, and pivoting creates another large data structure. Sometimes you must do it, but in this case you can go directly to the result skipping the intermediate large data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
baseCols <- paste0('x', 1:2)
result <- setDT(data) |> melt(measure.vars = patterns(baseCols), value.name = baseCols)
result[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(date), .SDcols=baseCols]
##        date  x1  x2
## 1: 1/1/2018   9  12
## 2: 2/1/2018 399 132
## 3: 3/1/2018 999 932
```